# Create a "like/unlike" functionality for ImageView

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a like/unlike functionality like Facebook and Instagram.

```
<ImageView
   android:onClick="onLikeClick"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:background="@drawable/your_feed_post_holder_state_fire"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="25dp"
   android:layout_height="25dp" />
```

Here is what I'm doing,

```
Boolean clicked = true;


public void onLikeClick(View view) {
    if (clicked) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_selected);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_unselected);
    }
}
```

The icon changes on first click, but on second click nothing happens.

Once a user presses on the ImageView a new image will replace, but if the user presses on the ImageView it will put the default image and so on back and forth.

Comment: ok, you told us what you want. Now tell us why you can't do that. What is a problem?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/how-to-manage-like-unlike-system-efficiently-in-your-android-application-5a82ff0a6bfe

Comment: I edit my post :) @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Update the clicked value on each click.

Comment: you never change the `clicked` value. It is always true. You need to change it inside `if/else`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update value of your `boolean` `clicked` variable  in your **`onLikeClick()`** method

```
public void onLikeClick(View view) {
    if (clicked) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_selected);
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_unselected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Boolean clicked = true;
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clicked) {
                clicked = false;
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_selected);
            } else {
                clicked = true;
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_unselected);
            }
        }
    });
```